# Ruby on Rails Complex Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Controller

```
    def create
        radgroup1 = Radgroup.new(groupname: radgroup_params[:groupname],
                                 attribute: "MaxTimeLimit",
                                 op:        ":=",
                                 value:     radgroup_params[:time])

        radgroup2 = Radgroup.new(groupname: radgroup_params[:groupname],
                                 attribute: "MaxDownLimit",
                                 op:        ":=",
                                 value:     radgroup_params[:downlimit])

        radgroup3 = Radgroup.new(groupname: radgroup_params[:groupname],
                                 attribute: "MaxUpLimit",
                                 op:        ":=",
                                 value:     radgroup_params[:uplimit])

        respond_to do |format|
            if radgroup1.save && radgroup2.save && radgroup3.save
```

And here is form:

```
    <%= form_tag "/radgroup_controller/create" do %>
      <%= text_field_tag "groupname", "default info" %>
      <%= text_field_tag "time", "default info" %>
      <%= text_field_tag "downlimit", "default info" %>
      <%= text_field_tag "uplimit", "default info" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
    <% end %>
```

According to this structure, I can not do the index page. Can you help me?

[existing index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4hyX.jpg)

index page I want, as in the picture

[index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1gW6.jpg)

Comment: Use separate forms with `id` as a hidden attribute for it. It sends a put request to the update action. It also seems like you need some kind of JS interactions happening here. You could use Jquery to change the index table view to form fields.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast